# Visual Studio Workflow Set People Field

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, person

I am new to Visual Studio Workflows, so please excuse my ignorance. I am having an issue setting the value of a People field. I have an Account Id coming from an InfoPath form. I need my workflow to take that value and insert/convert it to the value of the Person column.

**Account Id**

```
domain\username
```

**Workflow Code**

```
private void onWorkflowActivated(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{            
    String acctId = (String)workflowProperties.Item["Account Id"];
    acctId = "-1;#" + acctId;//I've been told this is the format the Person column is expecting
    workflowProperties.Item["Stakeholders"] = acctId;

    var s = workflowProperties.Item["Stakeholders"];//This is just a test
}
```

The current result is that the `Stakeholders` field is null. I would like it to be a Person Object with the value provided by the `Account Id` column. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are setting a value but not updating the item, i'd expect a .Update() in there

Comment: where does that method exist? I'm not seeing it in the `workflow.Item["Stakeholders"]` object

Comment: something like workflowProperties.Item.Update();

Comment: also is this the case? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61518c32-b6a8-45c8-9b8e-deba1acc677c/workflowpropertiesitemfield-value-?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a value but not updating the item, I'd expect a .Update() in there.

```
workflowProperties.Item["Stakeholders"] = acctId;
workflowProperties.Item.Update();
```

Also, this may be affecting you:

> If your field "" is field on the Infopath form and you
>   have chose that field to be available on the form library then one
>   thing you should check is that while you are adding a column to be
>   available in the form library there is a check box at the bottom of
>   that screen. That checkbox reads
>
> "Allow users to edit data in this field by using a datasheet or
>   properties page"
>
> By default this check box is not checked. Can you please try checking
>   this checkbox on the fields you want to update from your workflow?

From https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61518c32-b6a8-45c8-9b8e-deba1acc677c/workflowpropertiesitemfield-value-?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy